# I can click with a mouse but not move a cursor

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, cursor, mouse-cursor

It happened suddenly. I have not installed anything new on my PC.
I restarted it and then my mouse seems not to work.
The cursor was in the middle of the screen and it was invisible.
I was not able to see it or move it. I was able to click.
I plugged in another mouse. The cursor appeared and I was able to see and move it using new mouse.
Using old mouse I am still able to click but not to move.

How to make this mouse work?

Comment: Either the old mouse is broken, or it doesn't have the right drivers installed. What kinda of mouse is it? What is your computer info? We're going to need more information in order to help.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like this mouse may have broken. The best way to tell is to plug up the old mouse up to a different computer to see if it has issues on that one as well. If it works fine on a different computer than this would mean you're having driver issues with that mouse on the first PC.

If it's a special type of mouse try and re-install the drivers. If it's a generic mouse than it's probably just finally bit the dust.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of saving your own valuable time.
You should just buy a new mouse.
They seldom have out of the box defective issues.
They come with there own new drivers.

A mouse can be acquired at most computer stores very economically.
This is verified by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to fix this by re-installing the mouses's driver. It's also possible your mouse has reached it's end of life.

**Steps for re-installing mouse drivers:**

[image]

Go to "Control Panel/Hardware and Sound/Devices and Printers". Find your mouse, right click on it, and chose "remove device".

[image]

You will get a prompt asking if you are sure, click "yes". Your mouse will now stop working.

Disconnect your mouse from the computer, wait a few seconds, and then reconnect it. If the mouse is plug-n-play it will install the drivers again automatically, and resume functioning. If your mouse requires manual drivers (eg: came with a driver cd) then you will need to install them (so you might want to temporarily also connect your other mouse so you can access the drivers).

**Notes:**

- These instructions are for Windows 8, so the screenshots may be slightly different from what you see in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I was having this same issue and I just took out my batteries, and put the exact same pair I took out back in, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this Lenovo N100 wireless for more than 3 years. Today, as I was working on my laptop with the mouse it suddenly stopped moving. I can click all 3 buttons but cannot move around the cursor. So I googled for solutions. I found a few suggestions like removing and re-inserting the USB sensor, taking out the battery and putting back again, and uninstalling the driver, re-installing again. But none of them worked.
At last I switched of the mouse. Then I pressed down all the 3 buttons and switched on the mouse. At last it was working.
I hope this helps all who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, try unplugging the mouse and plugging it back in. It happens on my Windows 7 when resuming from sleep and that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue that I can click the right,left and scroll button but can not move cursor so I tried to resolve this issue.The issue is inside the mouse the small block of laser is misplaced. So just open the mouse and reassemble that its very simple.
I am using Logitech M235 mouse and there is only one screw in battery holder just remove that and place the laser source at right place in mouse.

Answer (score -2):

I've tried almost half of the things people have said to do on about 10 websites now. None of them worked. The mouse might be dead, just buy or use your new one. It's the same thing for me, I can left click, right click, and I can scroll up and down just fine but the cursor will not move. My keyboard mouse pad works just fine, it's just the USB mouse. I'll just deal with the fact that it's a dead mouse, and buy a new one that will break in at least 1-2 years at staples...